# Types do Vuex usando getters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
import * as types from './types'
export default {

    // -=-=-==- OK -=-=-=-== //
    //return first item
    first(state, getters){
        return getters.list[0];
    },

    //retorn all itens from my api
    list: state => {
        return state.list
    },


    // -=-=-==- ERROR -=-=-=-== //

    //return first item 
    [types.FIRST](state, getters){
        //how change .all for types.all
        //return getters.[types.ALL][0] this exemple is worng
        return getters.all[0];

    },
    //retorn all itens
    [types.ALL]: state => {
        return state.list
    }

}
```

Como faço para utilizar o `[type.ALL]` dentro de outro getter como no exemplo acima, sem os types eu consigo acessar um getter dentro de outro facilmente, mas como preciso usar os types não consegui uma maneira de chamar o getter all dentro do list utilizando `[type.ALL]`

Comment: Esse arquivo são só getters? essas funções não deviam estar dentro de um objeto 'getters'? e tente o seguinte onde está dando erro: `return getters[type.ALL]()[0]`, se der certo coloco uma resposta explicando.